# How to show $n^{1/n}$ is bounded below by $1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know there are a lot of posts of a similar nature but I cannot find one that helps me understand my question properly. The question is broken up into steps and this is the first part of it, later parts ask to show its decreasing for $n\ge3$ and to then compute the limit of the sequence.

I want to show that $n^{1/n}$ is bounded below by one. I cannot use L'Hopitals rule, I'm learning about monotone sequences so I want to use something different.

I have read so many different ways of doing it, but I think all of these have been about proving the sequence converges, not showing it is bounded below by 1 (unless this is the same thing!?).

Please could someone help me understand how to show this sequence is bounded below by 1? I'm not even sure where to start to be honest.

Comment: $n>1$ now take the $n^{th}$ root (Note that $y=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is monotonically increasing). and we have $n^{\frac{1}{n}} > 1^{\frac{1}{n}} =1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $n\geq 1$, then $n^{1/n}\geq 1^{1/n}=1$.

Comment: Why do you only replace one 'n' with 1, not both?

Comment: I don't follow. Here I simply use the fact that if $0<x\leq y$, then $x^{a}\leq y^{a}$ for $a\geq 0$.

Comment: Oh I see, ok thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Any* root of *any* number greater than or equal to $1$ is greater than or equal to $1$. Because if $a\in(0,1)$, then $a^n<1$, for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, $a$ cannot be the $n$<sup>th</sup> of a number greater than or equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^{1/n}$ , $x\ge 1$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

$f'(x) = (1/n) x^{(1/n -1)} \gt 0.$

$ f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Hence:

For $ n \ge 1$ , we have  $n^{1/n} \ge 1^{1/n} =1.$